# key value in ng-repeat and large JSON

Tags: html, json, html-lists

I have jsons like this one:

JSON "myWelcome"

```
[
    {"BACKGROUND": {
        "BACK": {
            "NAME": "asd"},
        "AGE": "13",
        "YEAR": "2016"
    }},
    {"NAILS": {
        "BACK": {
            "NAME": "asd"},
        "AGE": {
            "AG": "14"},
        "YEAR": "2014",
        "CENT": "dsds"
    }}
]
```

What i need to do is show everything from this json in `<ul>` or table, but not by name. My HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in myWelcome">
                         <ul ng-repeat="val in value">
                             <ul ng-repeat="(o, values) in val">
                                 <li>{{o}}</li><li>{{values}}</li>
                                 </ul>
                             </ul>
                         </ul>
```

It not quite work because "NAME" in "BACK" shows all.
Thanks for answers in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to print, with this unstructured data of JSON, you can't print everything simply by using ng-repeat, the non-equal depths of JSON doesn't let it, If you are sure that data is going to come in only this way, then and no other changes can happen, then it will be possible

Comment: So what - it is possible to show everything from this json by key and value?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, what key's value you want to print?

Comment: I want to print BACK.NAME or AGE.AG

Comment: and what about the only age part, in first element, you dont want that?

Comment: yes i want it too

Comment: i want every element of json in table or ul

Comment: i try to do that, but i can't show BACK.NAME and AGE.AG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140226/discussion-between-bafix2203-and-dark-lord).

Comment: @bafix2203 did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make it work, but it will only work on this data sample or a similar one, any changes in the JSON might break it also.

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in myWelcome">
    <ul ng-repeat="val in value">
        <ul ng-repeat="(o, values) in val">
            <li>{{o}}</li><li ng-if="key=='NAILS'&& o=='AGE'" >{{values.ag}}</li><li ng-if="!key=='NAILS'&& o=='AGE'">{{values}}</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove all the properties having key as `NAME` recursively then iterate using `ng-repeat`.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = [
    {"BACKGROUND": {
        "BACK": {
            "NAME": "asd"},
        "AGE": "13",
        "YEAR": "2016"
    }},
    {"NAILS": {
        "BACK": {
            "NAME": "asd"},
        "AGE": {
            "AG": "14"},
        "YEAR": "2014",
        "CENT": "dsds"
    }}
];

function removeMeta(obj) {
  for(prop in obj) {
    if (prop === 'NAME')
      delete obj[prop];
    else if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object')
      removeMeta(obj[prop]);
  }
};

removeMeta(jsonObj);

console.log(jsonObj);
```